# Google Sheets - Group By If/Then Buckets, Calculated Values

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, group-by, google-sheets-query

In Google Sheets, I'm trying to write a Query (not a stand alone Pivot Table nor script), which groups by a calculated value based on an if/then statement.

**Here's my sample data:**

```
Name    Days
Bob     0
Ed      1
Frank   2
Joey    4
Deluth  7
Henry   12
```

Grouping by column B is fairly straight forward:

```
=QUERY(A1:B7,"SELECT B, COUNT(B) GROUP BY B")
```

which outputs:

```
Days    count
0       1
1       1
2       1
4       1
7       1
12      1
```

But what I'm trying to do is group the days in to specific buckets. The buckets and desired output would be this **desired output**:

```
Days    count
0       1
1       1
2-5     2
6-9     1
10+     1
```

So it's almost an "if 0 then '0', if 1 then '1', if >1 AND <=5 then '2-5', etc., with a Group By at the end? How would this be written in QUERY format?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you had the upper limit of each range in (say) G2:G6, you could use Frequency to get the result:

```
=frequency(B2:B,G2:G)
```

Then you could combine this with your bin cells to get the two columns together:

```
=ArrayFormula({D2:D6,frequency(B2:B,G2:G)})
```

Extracting the upper limit from your bin cells is a bit awkward, but you could put it all together like this without a helper column:

```
=ArrayFormula({D2:D6,frequency(B2:B,--(right(D2:D5,len(D2:D5)-iferror(find("-",D2:D5),0))))})
```

[image]

Note that you don't need to define the '10+' range except for display purposes, Frequency automatically groups all remaining values (above 9) into a separate bin.

If you preferred, you could recode the original day values using a series of nested if statements or (better) vlookup and pass the result through to a query with grouping.

Comment: Awesome answer Tom, didn't know about frequency!

Comment: Thanks - yes Frequency is a surprisingly useful function, used in excel for counting unique values (less so in Google sheets because you have Unique & CountUnique functions) and also useful with repeated sequences of characters or numbers.

Answer (score 4):

If a helper column is allowed then (with a little cheating for the sake of the ordering) you could apply your existing formula with only changing A1 to A2:

Insert a new ColumB and in B2 and copied down to suit:

```
=lookup(C2,{0,1,2,6,9},{"00","01","02-5","06-9","10+"})
```